# How to return to the script once sudo is done

Tags: shell, ssh, sudo

I am on a server and running a script file that has following code.

```
ssh username@servername
sudo su - root
cd /abc/xyz
mkdir asdfg
```

I am able to ssh... but then the next command is not working.. the script is not sudo-ing. any idea?

Edit: Able to create a mech id and then do the things.. though still looking for the answer to above question :|

Comment: What error are you seeing in your shell?

Comment: @StevenSchobert - no error,. I am on the servername box. and not returning back from where I began.

Comment: try `exit` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your command will "stuck" on the first line because it will go into an interactive mode. The ssh command will require a password to be provided by a user (unless there is an sshkey being used) . And if the ssh is logged into the remote server then it will wait for user commands from standard input.

Secondly the lines following the ssh command will be executed only when the first process has exited. This is why your script is not "sudoing" - it's waiting for the ssh to end.

So if your point is to run a command on a remote server then put the command as a parameter into the same line as ssh connection. In your case:

```
ssh user@server sudo su - root
```

But this will not be of satisfaction for you. I suggest you create a script of what you want to execute on the remote server and then execute the script.

```
ssh user@server scriptName
```

The sudo thing here is very tricky because again your script might get stuck in the interactive mode waiting for a password to be inserted so I suggest you think again on the basis of the script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I am providing the password for the ssh. Now once I'm done with entering password, the sudo command is not executing. I am now in the destination server and not the source one.

Comment: If you are providing the password for the ssh then you run the script manually. If so you can also provide the sudo / su passwords on the remote server. I suggest you create the script on the remote server and run the script remotely after connection as an ssh parameter. Just create the script file called i.e. `runme.sh` on the remote server and put the linex you want to have executed into that script

Answer (score 0):

mb47!

You want to run the script on the remote computer, correct?

On the remote machine, create a file containing the commands you would like to execute.

Then, on the other machine, run `ssh user@machine /path/to/script/you/created/earlier`

I hope this helps!

ALinuxLover